# What are the "U" and "G" time formats?

Tags: date, date-time, formatting

In WordPress time functions, such as [`get_post_time()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_time/), one can pass a couple of formats that I do not understand what they do. Those are `U` and `G`. What are those exactly? Documentation is pretty vague.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not WP specific, here is the complete list: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @disinfor - Ah, thank you.

Comment: @disinfor can you post that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @TomJNowell Done and Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `U` and `G` are not WordPress specific. `get_post_time()` is using the same datetime formats as the default PHP `date` method.

Here is the documentation for all of the formats:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Specific to the question:

`U` is *Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)*

`G` is *24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros. 0 through 24*